# how to implement listactivity without extend it

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I want to implement ListView  without extend listActivity, and I dont know how to implement it. I just cant do getListView(); because I am not extened from listActivity. can you give an example code the I will take care of the listview to do this ->   lv.setAdapter(listAdapter)

my xml looks like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconremove"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
         android:src="@drawable/removeicon"
      android:visibility="gone"
          />
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and my code:

```
public class ListRss extends SherlockActivity  {
    ActionBar actionbar; 
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ArrayList<rssLinkAndTitle> ListRssLinkAndTitle=new ArrayList();
    //public ArrayList listValue=new ArrayList();
    RssArrays rssparser=new RssArrays();
    Context con;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.titlesrss);
            actionbar=getSupportActionBar();
            con=getApplicationContext();
        //  ListRssAdpter listAdapter;

            ListView    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.linearLa ); 

            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
lv.setAdapter(listAdapter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to implement ListView without extend listActivity

Note that there is a `SherlockListActivity` that you can use.

> I just cant do getListView(); because I am not extened from listActivity.

Correct. You need to call `setContentView()` with the ID of a layout resource that contains a `ListView`. Then, you can retrieve that `ListView` via `findViewById()`, the same as you would for any other widget.

Answer (score 0):

you can create listview in your layout and create listview object refer it in code you can make it without need to extends lisivew activity

`<ListView android:id="@+id/list1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>`

hope i get your point

Comment: can u give me an example of xml

Comment: @VitalyMenchikovsky i edit the post with xml  you will put with another views in it